# Python: Adding dictionary values to form new tuple-keyed dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary as follows (with some lists):

```
units = ['a','b']
nums = ['1','2']
ratios = ['alpha', 'beta']

d = {'a_1_alpha':4, 'a_1_beta' :1, 'a_2_alpha' :2, 'a_2_beta': 3, 'b_1_alpha':2}
```

How do i from a new dictionary which:

- forms a key comprising of tuple (num,ratio) #items from list nums & ratios
- the value would be the sum of the earlier dictionary (d) value.

i.e.

```
new_d = { ('1','alpha'): 6, ('1','beta'): 1, ('2','alpha'): 2, ('2','beta'): 3}
```

I have the following code, but doesn't seem right.

```
new_d = {}
for num in nums:
    for ratio in ratios:
        for k,v in d.items():
            if ratio in k:
                try:
                    oldval = dict[num,ratio]
                except:
                    oldval = 0
                new_d[(num,ratio)] = oldval + v

for p,q in new_d.items():
    print p,q
```

Please help to comment/advice.
Thanks :).

Comment: In new_d, should ('1','beta') be "1" instead of "0"?

Comment: @dusan: yeap..! typo.. editted!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two outer loops are redundant, simply iterate over the key-value pairs of `d`.  You can easily extract the three components of a key using `split()`.  Here's the code:

```
new_d = {}
for k, v in d.items():
   u, n, r = k.split('_')
   new_d[(n, r)] = v + new_d.get((n, r), 0)
```

Comment: Sweet! I thought of using `split` but outside the dictionary and code went messy. thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that this also avoids using an overly broad 'except:' - see http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except for why this is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
new_d = {}
for n in nums:
    for r in ratios:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if r in k and n in k:
                try:
                    old = new_d[(n, r)]
                except:
                    old = 0
                new_d[(n, r)] = v + old

for p, q in new_d.items():
    print (p, q)
```

Btw. you also forgot to check that `n in k` when determining whether the key is viable.

Answer (score 2):

OR using [collections](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) module:

```
d = {'a_1_alpha':4, 'a_1_beta' :1, 'a_2_alpha' :2, 'a_2_beta': 3, 'b_1_alpha':2}

from collections import defaultdict

new_d = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in ((tuple(k.split('_')[1:]),v) for k,v in d.iteritems()):
    new_d[k] += v
```